# Running a function when a (scheduled) post get published

Tags: php, wordpress

Whenever a post on my blog gets published, I want to run the `create_api_cache()`-function. To achieve this, I have the attached piece of code in my `functions.php`.

It works when I publish a post directly when i'm done with writing it. But when I schedule the post for a later moment, the function doesn't run at all. Is there another action I have to link to the function to achieve such behaviour?

```
add_action('new_to_publish', 'create_api_cache');
add_action('draft_to_publish', 'create_api_cache');
add_action('pending_to_publish', 'create_api_cache');
add_action('pre_post_update', 'create_api_cache');
add_action('future_to_publish', 'create_api_cache');

function create_api_cache() {
    global $post;
    $postname = $post->post_name;

    if(strlen($postname)) {
        $url = 'http://api.dummydomain.com/1/cache/create/' . $postname;
        file_get_contents($url);
    }

}
```

Comment: Not knowledgeable when it comes to WordPress but I'm guessing that a different function is being used when publishing scheduled posts.

Comment: Are you expecting the action to fire when the scheduled post's publication date rolls around?

Comment: Interesting. I would expect that to work. How are you testing this?

Comment: @s_ha_dum By actually scheduling a post and wait till it gets published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there isn't a way to do this kind of thing in functions.php. For now, a cronjob will be my solution.